# Click on links that add text values to inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**What I'm trying to do!** Rank your top 10 movies in order from 1-10.
When a link is clicked it should add the text value to the input and a button that removes the value. The process should be repeated until all inputs have a value.

**My horrible code!**
When I click a link, it adds the value to all inputs. How do I click a link add the value to input1, click another link add the value to input2, etc.

**HTML**

```
<div class="movies">
  <a href="#">Titanic</a>
  <a href="#">Rainman</a>
  <a href="#">Forrest Gump</a>
</div>

<ol>
  <li>
    <input type="text">
    <button class="remove">X</button>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="text">
    <button class="remove">X</button>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="text">
    <button class="remove">X</button>
  </li>
</ol>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.movies a').click(function() {
   var value = $(this).text();
   var input = $('input')
   input.val(value);
$('button').show();

});

$('button').click(function() {
   $('input').val("");
   $(this).hide();
});
```

See Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ericgray/yp2ee/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` to select the next input with no current value.

```
$('.movies a').click(function() {
    var value = $(this).text();
    var input = $('input').filter(function () {
        return this.value === ''
    }).eq(0);
    input.val(value);
    input.next().show();
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yp2ee/3/

The above code will only select input elements where the value is blank and then it only selects the first one returned by the `.filter()` function. This way you only change the value of a single input and only the first blank one.

I also updated the show/hide code for the buttons by showing and hiding the element relatively to the input element or button element clicked:

```
input.next().show();
```

**UPDATE**

You can use `.data()` to store the state of the links so you can only add a movie once:

```
$('.movies a').data('clicked', false).click(function() {
    if ($(this).data('clicked') === false) {
        $(this).data('clicked', true);
        ...
    }
});
```

Then in your "X" button click event handler you can change the data regarding that value before removing the value:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var val = $(this).prev().val();
    $('.movies a').filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() === val
    }).data('clicked', false);
    $(this).prev().val("");
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Here is a demo of my update: http://jsfiddle.net/yp2ee/7/

Comment: That's awesome jasper. The only thing I need to fix is allowing only one movie per input. For example if Rain man is already selected it can't be put in another input. Thanks man.

Comment: Now that is exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate it!

Comment: Hey Jasper I'm trying to put the finishing touches on this script. My lack of Dom traversal knowledge is once again a roadblock. I would like to add a few more usability features. When a link is clicked I want to change the opacity and also add a span tag with a number that corresponds to the input. The Remove button will remove the opacity and remove the span tag. I thought I could get it working but ran into the same problem of all targets being manipulated at once. Check out my Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ericgray/F7j76/. Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: @Eric Doing things like selecting by tag will get you a nice starting point but you need to realize how things link together ideologically. I noticed in your new JSFiddle that you try to get the title of a `li` element by selecting all `li` elements in the DOM. This is unnecessary becase a few lines down the correct `input` element is selected. This means you can select the parent of that `input` to get the correct `li`. `var input =...; var li = input.parent();`. To further your knowledge, lookup jQuery DOM Traversal methods, it's actually pretty easy to get used to.

Comment: Thanks Jasper. I mostly write server side code in Ruby. I still have a lot to learn on the front end. I'll see if I can figure this out. I will research JQuery Dom Traversal. Thanks!

Comment: How can we achieve the same in vue-js ? any idea

Answer (score 0):

You are simply selecting the elements with its `tag` name. It will return `collection` of elements. So we don't need that. Right.? so what should we do is we have to filter the required element by using `.filter()` function by supplying the necessary condition[empty] to it.

Ok now we are having chances to get more than one empty text boxes, so in that situation we have to use `.first()` to select the first element from that collection.

Try,

```
$('.movies a').click(function() {
    var value = $(this).text();
    var input = $('input')
                .filter(function(){ return $.trim($(this).val()) == ""; })
                .first();
    input.val(value);
    input.next('button').show();
});

$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).prev('input').val("");
    $(this).hide();
 });
```

The above explanations would have given a minimum understanding about the mechanism. Ok now come to the point `.next()` and `.prev()`. Again you are selecting those buttons using the `tag` name. So actually what we need at this situation is to select the `button` next to the `input box` and vice versa. So we could use that both to accomplish what we needed.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yp2ee/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Another way: not upto standards, but readable

Modified the HTML a bit by adding classes and ids

http://jsfiddle.net/yp2ee/5/

```
$('.movies a').click(function() {
    var value = $(this).text();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.'+id).val(value).show();
    $('.'+id).next('button').show();
});

$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).prev('input').val("");
    $(this).hide();
 });
```

Comment: That works really good. I just need the order of precedence to work like Jasper's. If a value is removed I need the next value to start from the top. Hope I'm being clear. Thank you!